# Applying two keyword filters to SINGLE column in Datagridview. VB

Tags: vb.net, filter, datagridview, bindingsource

I've been struggling to figure out where this strand of code is going awry... I'm currently trying to filter a Column in my datagridview, via my binding source, with two Strings at the same time... I feel like I am possibly only off by one quotation mark or something silly but Ive been racking my brain for far too long now and want this to be done with.

```
    Me.ServiceCatalogDataBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("[Completion Status] like '%" & "Open" & "%'", "[Completion Status] like '%" & "In Progress" & "%'")
```

That is the code I'm using to try and filter the one column....
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using a String.Format statement for something that should be just concatenation?  Also include either the word **'And'** or **`Or`** between the two conditions.

Comment: A filter is simply a Boolean condition, i.e. you want to include only the records for which an expression evaluates to `True`.  If you have done ANYTHING at all regarding Boolean logic then you already know that you combine multiple Boolean expressions using `AND` and `OR` operators.  You do it in VB and you do it in SQL.  The specific appearance of the operator may change from language to language but Boolean logic works exactly the same way EVERYWHERE.  In this case, it would presumably be an `OR`, because that one column presumably won't contain both values at the same time.

Comment: I supposed I should have been more clear in regards as to what i had tried prior to running this string of code... I had obviously tried using boolean, and & or... the issue being that through all the attempts of using boolean operators, I was only ever able to filter one keyword at a time... Because @jmcilhinney, unfortunately I do want to filter one column and view all tickets that have either "Open" or "In Progress" in the row.

Comment: You're setting the `Filter` property of a `BindingSource`. The documentation for that property specifically states **"you can specify Boolean expressions using the syntax documented for the `DataColumn.Expression` property"**. Following that link you get **"Concatenation is allowed using Boolean AND, OR, and NOT operators"** and it specifically states that `And` and `Or` are reserved words. VS has a Help menu for a reason. If you tried actual Boolean logic, why did you not show us that?

Comment: You'll have to excuse me... I only put in the last the piece that i tried out... as i said in my original post, I have been racking my brain on this part for a while... that being a day or two. So I can definitely say that i have tried using the `And` and `Or` statements as a means of solving this issue... what I come across when using these however.... is it either only pulls the first or last half of the code.

Comment: For example, with this `Me.ServiceCatalogDataBindingSource.Filter = "[Completion Status] like '%" & "Open" & "%'" And "[Completion Status] like '%" & "In Progress" & "%'" ` My column will only display the rows with "Open" in them.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears that i just had the syntax of my code wrong... and then actually using = instead of like made the code function properly. While that will possibly have drawbacks, I will build in a work around for it.

```
    Me.ServiceCatalogDataBindingSource.Filter = "[Completion Status] = 'Open' OR [Completion Status] = 'In Progress'"
```